# What does assigns mean in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, bdd

What does that line of code do?

```
assigns(:articles).should eq([article])
```

in the following rspec

```
  describe "GET #index" do
    it "populates an array of articles" do
      article = Factory(:article)
      get :index
      assigns(:articles).should eq([article])
    end

    it "renders the :index view" do
      get :index
      response.should render_template :index
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`assigns` relates to the instance variables created within a controller action (and assigned to the view).

---

to answer your remark in comments, I guess that:

- 1) your index action looks like `@articles = Articles.all` (I hope you use pagination though)
- 2) prior to the spec block above, you have one article created in db (or I hope you stub db queries in db)
- 1 + 2 => `@articles` should contain one article, that's your spec expectation

Comment: I just don't understand how it populates an array of articles, and how   do we check that it works

Answer (score 2):

In a controller spec, `assigns` will take a symbol (e.g. `assigns(:variable)`) and returns the controller's corresponding instance variable (e.g. `@variable` in the controller).

So in the question's example, the index method of the controller evidently sets `@articles` to a list of articles, and `assigns` merely makes that value available in the spec.

`assigns` has been moved into a gem: https://github.com/rails/rails-controller-testing.

https://joshfrankel.me/blog/accessing-instance-variables-within-a-rspec-controller-test/