# How to know the flow of the controller method using Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I have two dependent drop down.One gives me orgname and other drop down populates on selecting a orgname, That is teamname.
This is my github_leader_board_spec.rb

```
describe "github_leader_board" do
    before do
      @obj = DashboardsController.new
    end
    context "with session" do

      subject { get :github_leader_board, :params => { :orgname => "test", :teamname=> "team"}}
      it "returns http success" do
        expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
      end
      it "executes other functions" do
        expect(@org_data).not_to be_nil
        expect(@obj.get_team_api("DevCenter")).not_to be_nil
      end
    end
  end
```

This is my controller method

```
def github_leader_board
        myhash = {}
        @points_hash = {}
        member_data = []
        @org_data = get_org_api
        @orgs = get_names(org_data)
        team_data = get_team_api(params[:orgname])
        @teams = get_names(team_data)
        teamid = get_team_id(team_data)
        @teams.each_with_index {|k,i|myhash[k] = teamid[i]}
        myhash.each do |key,value|
            if key == params[:teamname]
                member_data = get_members("#{value}")
            end
        end
        @memberids = get_names(member_data)
        member_names = get_member_names(@memberids)
        review_comments = get_reviewcoments(@memberids)
        reactions = points(@memberids)
        points = [review_comments, reactions].transpose.map {|x| x.reduce(:+)}
        member_names.each_with_index {|k,i|@points_hash[k] = points[i]}

    end
```

If i run my spec file it says, undefined @org_data. The function inside the github_leader_board controller is not calling the get_org_api and storing the value to the @org_data variable.
Can anybody suggest what is wrong with the code and how can i improve it. As i'm new to ror.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Check out `pry` and `byebug` - well known debuggers in Ruby world.

Comment: May be, you are not calling the action at all. Call `subject` in the first line of your `it` block and then check `expect(assigns(:org_data)).not_to be_nil`. Note: You cannot access the instance variable set in controller by simply doing `@org_data` in RSpecs. Use [`assigns`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16133166/what-does-assigns-mean-in-rspec) for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you could use a test of the type controller, instead of instantiating your controller and then use the RSpec method `assigns` ([docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs)) to test your instance variables, something like this:

```
RSpec.describe DashboardsController, :type => :controller do
   context "with session" do
      # ...
      it "executes other functions" do
        expect(assigns(:org_data)).not_to be_nil
      end
    end
end
```

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs

Also, if you want to check the flow, and debug your code, you can use the gems `pry`, `pry-rails` and `pry-nav` as @Marek Lipka stated.

Comment: DashboardsController github_leader_board with session Checks for the variable
     Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:org_data)).not_to be_nil

       expected: not nil
            got: nil 
This is the error i'm getting

Comment: @AshwiniRamesh you need to change the `describe` line to pass your actual controller class and not a string, this is how rspec knows it's a "controller spec"